# Any PowerShell Script to Backup and restore Ms-sql database using dB username and password?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, scripting, sql, vbscript

I am looking for a PowerShell script which can take backup and restore MS-SQL databases using SQL authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Backup-DbaDatabase` cmdlet from [dbatools](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Backup-DbaDatabase), you just need to install the module first and then set the `-SqlCredential` parameter with the username and password. Lots of examples out there.